# How to use .net aspx page inside one .aspx page without using IFRAME tag. I have used jquery tab but its not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-tabs

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

I have used 3tabs in one ASPX page. Each tabcontent having one aspx page how can i load one aspx page in to another aspx page.

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#Quicktabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
                ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="Quicktabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../admin/Generalpage.aspx">
                    <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="General Page" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="../admin/Home.aspx">
                    <asp:Label ID="label2" Text="LoginPage" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="../admin/signup.aspx">
                    <asp:Label ID="label3" Text="Signup" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why you can't use ascx instead of aspx?

Comment: its already well developed page, we want to show all three pages in one .aspx page using jquery tab. any solution ASAP?

Comment: If it's already a "well developed page" then does it already have page headers/footers?  Does the page include 'head' or 'body' element?

Comment: What's the issue you're having?   Using relative urls ("../admin/") will open a page *relative* to the *url* that you're currently on - which is likely to be, but not always the aspx page path.  Try: `<a href="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/")%>/admin/GeneralPage.aspx">`